# Is there no function in SurfaceView to control the Backward button for Android?

Tags: android, surfaceview

Is there no function in SurfaceView to control the Backward button for Android?

OnBackPressed()not working here.

help..me..

Answer (score 0):

What if you use?

```
onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Although most likely you will use the view inside a `Fragment` or an `Activity`, then would be more appropriate to handle `onBackPress()` there

Comment: I still can't control the backbutton.

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        synchronized (mHolder) {
            switch (keyCode) {

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    Log.e(TAG,"onKeyDownTest");
                    //System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:

            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
    }